# How to fix 'A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree.' in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I display a `CupertinoPopupSurface` and use a `Dismissible` widget to dismiss the dialog with a gesture. When I swipe down I call  `Navigator.of(context).pop();` to close the dialog and return to the previous screen but I am getting and error which says `Dismissible` is still part of the tree.

I tried providing a unique key `Dismissible(key: UniqueKey(), ...)` but it still is not working.

```dart
 CupertinoPopupSurface(
   isSurfacePainted: false,
   child: Container(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
     child: Dismissible(
       key: UniqueKey(),
       direction: DismissDirection.down,
       onDismissed: (direction) {
         Navigator.of(context).pop();
       },
       child: Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             borderRadius:
                 BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(40)),
           ),
           child: ZoneFilter(
               visit: visit, accountsViewModel: accountsViewModel)),
     ),
   ),
 );
```

I would like to call `Navigator.of(context).pop();` and get rid of the Dismissible widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dismissible widget is inside your Popup, not around it as it should be. You can make it work by changing it to the code below. Fair warning though, it will feel slow because the darkened background of the dialog will only disappear once the dismiss animation finishes.

```
return Dismissible(
    key: UniqueKey(),
    direction: DismissDirection.down,
    onDismissed: (direction) => Navigator.of(context).pop();,
    child:  CupertinoPopupSurface(
      isSurfacePainted: false,
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius:
            BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(40)),
          ),
          child: ZoneFilter(
            visit: visit, accountsViewModel: accountsViewModel)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I tried but it did not worked, I ended up using `showModalBottomSheet`

Comment: Can you tell me what results you saw? I copied your exact code, only replacing your zonefilter as it needed a class you didn't share.